# woocommerce api returning html, not json

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a test site which calls are returning in JSON no problems,

But on my live site (different from test site), it is returning html.

I have also put in the header "Content-Type: application/json" but it is still returning HTML.

I have:

W3 Total Cache
and woo commerce Version 2.6.14 installed.

I know it is an old version and I am upgrading but there is alot to sort out before upgrading, but this shouldn't cause this issue should it?

I am calling on postman.

Why is HTML being returned on API Calls and how do I fix it?

Comment: Actually, it is the site is blahblah.com/store/ but when I call it is just returning the website blahblah.com/ and all the html of that page?

Comment: was htaccess issue